# Changing text isnt working in this instance, using jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<a class="create-password-account" style="vertical-align:middle" href="/account/signup/?login_provider=local">Create a password-protected account</a>
```

This is what my login says on my site. I want to change the text to something simple like "Sign up here for a new account." I need a method which only uses Javascript/jQuery; I cant change the original code.

I've tried several things, but none of them work:

1. `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/Create a password-protected account/g, "Sign up here for a new account");`
2. `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("Create a password-protected account", "Sign up here for a new account");`
3. `$('.create-password-account').html('Sign up here for a new account');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you

- Include jQuery
- Wrap the line in a document.onready method

See example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.create-password-account').text('Sign up here for a new account');
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6N9Py/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `text()` to change the text value

```
 $('.create-password-account').text('Sign up here for a new account');
```

Comment: nope, i copied and pasted the exact thing , it doesnt work. Strange, even my previous methods worked for other texts. But for this it doesnt .

Comment: whats fiddle? im sorry i dont understand :/

Comment: i can share the website url? will that be ok?

Comment: @Tharindu did you include jquery

Comment: @Tharindu include  jquery  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>